# Convex hull for convex polygons

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

Is there something tricky about that? Or I should use some of the standard [convex hull algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) ?
I mean, I don't see anything different between creating convex hull for a set of points and creating convex hull for *non-overlapping* convex polygons (2D)?

Answer (score 4):

If this is in 2D, *Yes*, you should just use a standard algorithm. The [Graham scan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan) is perfect for your application, as it will not waste much time beyond sorting.
You can find code all over the web, including my own [here](http://maven.smith.edu/~orourke/books/ftp.html).

Comment: How about http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~orm/mergech.html ? (:

Answer (score 1):

Creating the convex hull of a finite set of points takes $\Omega(n\log n)$ steps in worst case, which means $n\log n$ is a lower bound for the complexity of every algorithm that solves this problem.

Otherwise you could sort random points (1D) faster that $n\log n$ by calculating the convex hull (2D) of the points $(p_i,p_i^2)$

Construction of the convex hull of a *simple polygon* is possible in $O(n)$ as shown for example by Preparata and Shamos in 1985: http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~athens/cs601/Preparata.html

Construction of the convex hull of a *convex polygon* is actually possible in $O(1)$ because the convex hull of a convex polygon is the polygon itself.